# Install COD file on BlackBerry OS 10

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde, blackberry-os6

I have developed BlackBerry Apps using Java SDK till BBOS 10 got released. But the recent BBOS 10 released doesn't provide Java SDK platform for developing the applications. 
So is there any way that I can run my previously developed applications(using Java SDK 5.0,6.0,7.0,7.1) on the BBOS 10 simulator/device.
Is BlackBerry on the process of releasing the Java SDK in the near future.??  
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you wrote [WebWorks](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/) application then you could recompile it to BB 10. Otherwise there is [no chance to run your app](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/DevCon-update-BB-Java-is-dead-no-java-support-for-QNX/td-p/1369863) on the BB 10. Unfortunately!